# Vim not recognizing some commands from vim-latex

Tags: vim, latex-suite

I have `vim-latex` installed via Vundle and I'm trying to disable some annoying mapping that it sets up by default. From the [docs](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html#environment-mappings) I know that, for example, I can use the following command to unmap `FEM`:

```
call IUNMAP('FEM','tex')
```

But when I type that I get the error `E117: Unknown function: IUNMAP`.

I have installed `vim-latex` with Vundle by including `Plugin 'LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX'` in my `vimrc` and I have just used the `PluginUpdate` command to update everything, which runs with no error, so I should have the latest version of the package.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you are missing [VimTeX](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). Please, give a look at [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2047/6498).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Useful link. However, I installed `vimtex` via Vundle and still got the same result when trying the `IUNMAP` command

Comment: my comment is a comment, not meant to be a solution. However, based on your link, it seems `IUNMAP` is a Vim-LaTeX thing. So if you switch to VimTeX, you don't have to worry about its mappings. Uninstall Vim-LaTeX and just forget about it.

Comment: Consider using `Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex'` to get vim-latex from [here](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex), which looks like a more official authoritative source for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the problem you're having is related to *where* you're getting your vim-latex from.

With:

```
Plug 'LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX'
```

You're getting it from [here](https://github.com/vim-scripts/LaTeX-Suite-aka-Vim-LaTeX), which you'll notice hasn't been updated since 2010. Looking at the `plugin/imaps.vim` file in that repository, you'll see there's a definition for function `IMAP()`, but not for `IUNMAP()`, which was probably introduced after the last date that repository was synced...

Use this source instead:

```
Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex'
```

Which will get it from [here](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) which is an official maintained location for this plug-in.

If you look at `plugin/imaps.vim` in that source tree, you'll notice `function! IUNMAP` is defined there.

Updating to the correct plug-in location should fix this problem for you (together with probably quite a few fixes from the last 10 years!)

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe I missed that.... In my defense the names don't exactly make this easy to spot

Answer (score 1):

The functions `IMAP()` and `IUNMAP()` are loaded by the vim-latex plug-in only *after* your vimrc is processed. So you need to execute them from a context where they're available.

Furthermore, in order to have your unmapping succeed, you need to actually execute it *after* the mapping was created, and mappings are typically created when the filetype is set.

The [documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html#overriding-macros) mentions that these overriding rules should be done in specific files:

> An important thing to note is that if you wish to over-ride macros created by Latex-Suite rather than merely create new macros, you should place the `IMAP()` (or `IUNMAP()`) calls in a script which gets sourced after the files in Latex-Suite.
>
> **A good place typically is as a file-type plugin file in the `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/` directory.** [...]
>
> For example, to delete a mapping, you can use
>
> ```
> call IUNMAP('FEM', 'tex')
> ```
>
> in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex_macros.vim`.

The documentation mentions that you should use a file in `ftplugin` after the filetype you use. Check `:set ft?` to confirm yours is indeed `tex`, in which case you can use `tex.vim`, `tex_something.vim` (like the suggested `tex_macros.vim`) or `tex/something.vim` (a subdirectory.)

Comment: Actually, `ft_anything.vim` and `ft/anything.vim` will work too.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ah! I knew about ft/something.vim but didn't know underscore also worked... I'll update the answer. Thanks for the catch!